# How to reduce the Google Map Api Cost or optimized approach for tracking and api hitting

Tags: android, node.js, rest, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are startup company in transport section.

We are getting a lot of charges for this like 400$ and above per day with consistent increase of users in the app .

1.We are using google map api and hitting every 2 second for smooth vehicle movement because if we increase the time limit than the problem is vehicle movement is jerking and jumping . we want smooth movement in an optimized way so as to reduce the cost .

Please suggest your opinion . Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5):

You must have to make a system to store or caching the data you get from google map api. You can use Mapbox to get the alternative solution. MapBox gives you 50000 free request per month per every api. I faced the same problem. I use both Google map api and Mapbox api and also cache the data to reuse.

For smooth vehicle animation you can follow this link: https://github.com/amanjeetsingh150/UberCarAnimation
Vehicle movement can be done offline. No need to pay for it.

And also, if you think, you can have a look at MapBox: http://mapbox.com/